# how to get data from the given json file

Tags: javascript, json

[This][1] is the link of my json file and i want to access its data into my ajax success function. tell me how can i do this?

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "abc" + imageId,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (d) {
             alert(imageId);
             var storyImage = d.data;
             alert(storyImage);
      }
 })
```

Comment: What is your actual problem ?

Comment: my problem is that i want to access data from the given url

Comment: and this loid will change when user click on other story

Comment: How is this a problem ? What goes wrong ? What does not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the object response is:

```
 {
 "http://www.livemint.com/template/features/webapps/encodeImage?loid=2.1.1521199245": {
     "data":"data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk..."}
}
```

So you can't say `d.data` you will have to do `d["http://www.livemint.com/template/..."]`

But you can do something like this:

```
var imageId = "2.1.1521199245"
var url = "http://www.livemint.com/template/features/webapps/encodeImage?loid=" + imageId;
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (d) {
              alert(imageId);
             var storyImage = d[url].data;
             alert(storyImage);
      }
 })
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cA396/

Comment: Yeah exactly we can't say d.data so thats why i am very confused to do this. You are to good and thanx a lot.

Comment: If it was the correct answer, then please mark it as the answer.. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need parse JSON into Object
http://www.json.org/js.html

If you do a crossdomain request $.ajax will be not work. See
[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)